# Network failure when booting with network cable plugged

Tags: networking

I now ran into this problem with my laptop. I can't establish an ethernet connection when I boot the system with network cable on. However, when I boot with network cable unplugged but connect it after the machine enters Ubuntu system, the network work alright.

The wireless network is not affected. The problem persists whether wireless is connected and disconnected. Thank you for your answer.

Some information:

My machine is a Thinkpad T440s with dual systems (win 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04)， UEFI boot.

```
$lspci
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 6b)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I218-LM (rev 04)

$ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 28:d2:44:2c:11:bf  
          inet6 addr: fe80::2ad2:44ff:fe2c:11bf/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:672 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:472 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:135127 (135.1 KB)  TX bytes:60358 (60.3 KB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f1600000-f1620000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:3056 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3056 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:514638 (514.6 KB)  TX bytes:514638 (514.6 KB)
```

Comment: Do you have another computer that you can use `Wireshark` on to see what's happening with DHCP during boot?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is problem on device boot order in bios. Go to bios and change order of boot devices or turn off PXE boot aka boot via lan card.